# How to prove this property for repeated squaring?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

This is from https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/14au/slides/lecture12-filled.pdf

This property is used for modular exponentiation, that is to do a problem like this (from slide 6)
[image]

Here is the property(slide 7)
[image]

How would you go about proving this?

The first thing I did was by definition of a mod m is congruent to a modulo m,

a mod m - a = km for some integer k

What step would you take next to prove this property?

Comment: What is your definition of "$a\bmod m$"? For me it is by definition the number $x$ in $[0,m)$ such that $x\equiv a\pmod m$. In that case there's nothing to prove.

Comment: a mod m is just the remainder when a is divided by m.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What's a if x is defined as a number in [0, m)?

Comment: @committedandroider: Um $a$ is one of the two inputs to the operation. Also, "the remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$" is not less in need of a definition than "$a\bmod m$" is.

Comment: cause x $\equiv\$ a(mod m) is saying m divides x - a. To me that isn't the same as saying, the remainder when a is divided by m.

Comment: @committedandroider: But you still haven't revealed your definition of "the remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$".

Comment: O sorry about that, from my book, we introduced "the notion a mod m to represent the remainder when an integer a is divided by the positive integer m".